# Date Format in Android for AM_PM

Tags: android

I need to display date and time in the format `Tue, Mar 29, 2016, 6.50 PM`, I have tried the following:

```
DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd, yyyy, h.mm a");
```

but this displays `a.m.` in Android but I need `AM`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: did you try this?  `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd, yyyy, h.mm aaa")`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by fixing locale like:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatShort = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa", Locale.US);
```

if you want a constant formatting then you have to apply a particular locale for simple date formate otherwise it will by default pick the device current locale and your formatting will change device to device basis.

Answer (score 0):

first convert date to string than replace the a.m or p.m to AM or PM you only need to check the condition if string.contains a.m or p.m than replace it

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
Date dt = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");

String result = sdf.format(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DateFormatSymbols to set the AM and PM strings to whatever you want, in your case all-caps.

The SimpleDateFormat constructor accepts the modified DateFormatSymbols object as an argument.

```
    DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols();
    String[] modifiedAmPm = {"AM", "PM"};
    symbols.setAmPmStrings(modifiedAmPm);

    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd, yyyy, h.mm a", symbols);
    String result = formatter.format(date);
```